# How can I link 3 PS4s together using a switch with no internet?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, networking

I'm trying to set up a LAN party for my family on three PS4 systems, using an unmanaged lan switch and three Ethernet cables. There should be no internet connection. We're trying to play COD WW2 Nazi zombies local play.

I've had two PS4s link with just an Ethernet cable using the IP address 192.168.1.2 and 3. I've also got two out of three PS4s working using the switch but I can’t get the third one to link up.

I've checked the cable and the port and everything is getting signal, and I've also tried changing the last digit of the IP address starting at 0 up to 7 and still nothing.

I'm not real smart with these kind of things so go easy on the technical terms, but I'm willing and wanting to learn. How can I get this working?

Comment: does your switch have separate lan ports for lan and for internet? it's is possible that 2 consoles are connected to lan ports and the last one is connected to internet port?